# Basic references to study the hyperbolic plane

Tags: reference-request, hyperbolic-geometry

I am an undergraduate math student and I want to introduce myself in the study of the hyperbolic plane. I'm looking for references on this topic to start getting into it. Could you recommend me some books?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not a comprehensive answer (hence the comment), but Patrick Ryan's [_Euclidean and Non-Euclidean Geometry_](https://archive.org/details/euclideannoneucl0000ryan) is a careful, friendly introduction to Euclidean, spherical, and hyperbolic geometry based in 2- and 3-dimensional linear algebra and systematically connecting to the synthetic viewpoint.

Comment: Thank you very much, i'll take a look @AndrewD.Hwang